# Hot deployment of java web module with maven in weblogic 10.3

Tags: deployment, maven, weblogic

1. I tried to search the steps involved in hot deploying the java web application in weblogic 10.3, but couldn't succeed. Can some one help me out in describing the steps required for hot deployment. I am using maven multi-module project(web module, .war file) with eclipse. Each time if any changes are there to java files I am rebuilding the entire project and redeploying it to test in web logic 10.3.
2. Also just want to under stand where can I find WEB-INF/classes (.class files) in weblogic directory? I could able to see all files except files under WEB-INF/classes in /servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user//war/...

Thanks
Santhosh